# how to retrieve the data from all the pages in python by selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to retrieve the data from all pages in the link bellow. I retrieve just the first page data, but I couldn't get the rest of the pages. Could you complete my code?

url: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/2021004/exp-eng.htm?r1=(1)&r2=0&r3=0&r4=12&r5=0&r7=0&r8=2022-02-01&r9=2022-02-01"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\Python310\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
table = driver.find_element_by_id('report_table')
body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
cells = body.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')

for cell in cells:
    print(cell.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium click() element method to click on the **Next** button, and using a **for loop**, you can iterate through all the pages.

For example,

```
# run the loop 26 times
for i in range(26):
    
    # your code
    table = driver.find_element_by_id('report_table')
    body = table.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')
    cells = body.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for cell in cells:
        print(cell.text)
        
    # click on the Next button    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
```